# PhpStorm Laravel 5.4 automatic facades support

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, facade

As you may know or not, Laravel 5.4 introduced automatic facades. I'm using PhpStorm and don't know if getting a working autocomplete is possible. Standard facades work because I'm using [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), but (I guess) automatic facades don't work. Is there any solution?

Comment: are you running the dev version of 5.4?

Answer (score 1):

As @jdenoc mentioned the package `laravel-ide-helper`, you can also try adding the gist [_ide_helper.php](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822)  file in the project's root folder, as Jeffrey Way briefly explained in [his tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using this composer package: [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).
It is a **Laravel 5 IDE Helper Generator**

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know of is to create your own helper file. In PhpStorm, create a `_ide_facades.php` file in the root of your project. Then you can add the structure of your methods. As a contrived example, say we have NameService we import as `Facades\App\Services\NameService`and implement as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

public class NameService
{
    public function upper(string $name): string
    {
        return str($name)->upper();
    }

    public function lower(string $name): string
    {
        return str($name)->lower();
    }
}
```

Then in our `_ide_facades.php:`

```
<?php
// @formatter:off

namespace Facades\App\Services\NameService {
    class NameService
    {
        public static function upper(string $name): string {}
        
        public static function lower(string $name): string {}
    }
}
```

Rinse and repeat for all your real-time facades adding each in their own namespace block. Hopefully someone will come up with a plugin or helper to do this automatically to spare us the effort of creating/maintaining manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpDocs in your codes for detection by phpstorm
eg: // * @method static static make(string $classname)